# Displaying tables below each other in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have to create a report where several tables are diplayed below each other. Each table gets its data from a SubDataset and contains none, one or more rows.

For the first version of the report, I've simply ignored the possibility of a table having no rows and put all tables below each other, each with the height of 1 row. The idea was, that if there is more than one row, the table will grow in height, which seems to work fine. I've given the first table a fixed position and set all subsequent ones to float. In iReport it looks like this:

[image]

But when I create a report, only the first table is at the expected position. The rest is displayed too low and overlaps:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this? I can't use subreports, because the report is stored in a database so I can't reference other reports. Is there maybe another alternative to subreports or tables?

Comment: You can find the complete source here: [http://pastebin.com/ZPKqwwvs](http://pastebin.com/ZPKqwwvs)

Comment: "I can't use subreports, because the report is stored in a database so I can't reference other reports." You can reference other reports when they are stored in the database, using the `repo:` syntax.

Comment: Didn't know about that, thanks. I'll look into it, but I'm not sure if that's an option, because the database does not store any information that would allow me to identify the report I want to embed.

Comment: Ben's comment is helpful if you are using JasperReports Server. If you aren't, then it won't be relevant. On the other hand... all you need is for the compiled subreport to be accessible on the classpath, so you should be able to use subreports. On the other hand... the table really should work, so switching to subreports is adding complexity that you probably don't need.

Comment: Since I have to finish the report as soon as possible, I've worked around the problem for now by using one big, ugly union select that allows me to display all data in one table. This is not the first problem with Jasper our team has run into, so we'll probably just drop it in the near future and switch to BIRT or Pentaho.

Answer (score 7):

You have the "Position Type" property set to "Fix Relative to Top". Change it to "Float".

Comment: Only the first of the three tables has a fixed position. This is okay, because it always starts at the same position.  
If I change it to float, it simply moves down to the rest of the tables, overlapping them.

Comment: Hmm... Yes, it's good to have the first one fixed and the other two floating. But the first table should appear in exactly the same place whether it is fixed of floating. The fact that it gets pushed down is perhaps a symptom of the underlying problem. You could try debugging by putting a Text Field or a line (also set to flow) between the tables, and see where it ends up.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into using subreports. I do create table followed by another (datasource is XML).

1. create subreport using xPath
2. Use Data Source Expression   property of the subreport to set the datasource for subreport
   `((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRXmlDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("/FUND_STATEMENT/FUNDS/FUND")`