# Print subreport one after another

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

Inside the detail section of the main report, I have created 2 subreports which are very much identical.  I have specified the height of these 2 subreports as 300 px on the main report so they occupy equal space  and appear as 2 boxes one after the another in the design.

The design of the subreport is as shown below. Its height is kept at 300px. The detail band iterates depending on the number of rows returned from the database. This could have 3 to 8 rows returned.

[image: Subreport1]

Now I want to display the subreports one after another as shown below without any white space in between them when I preview them. Right now I see white space between them when the 1st returns only 3 rows. How can we move the 2nd subreport so that it appears just after the last row of the 1st subreport.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Configure the detail band and the subreport component in your main report with a minimal height that will always be reached within your subreport, e.g. `5px`, as they will always stretch depending on your subreport output.

Second, check that there is no unneeded space in your subreport template at the bottom of your detail band.

Answer (score 0):

[mdahlman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8373/mdahlman) pointed the right answer for this question: [Displaying tables below each other in JasperReports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229676/displaying-tables-below-each-other-in-jasperreports)
'You have the "Position Type" set to "Fix Relative to Top". Change it to "Float"'.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many reasons for this. Check if the below steps are implemented:

1. Both the subreports should avoid top-bottom margins. (Right-click in grey area of the subreports and click "Remove report margins").
2. You might be having empty Summary band in the first subreport.
3. Position Type of both the subreports should be "Float".
4. Check if the sum of height of subrports(with data populated) does not go beyond the height of the parent report.